# How to remove the infront regular expression?

Tags: regex, matlab

How to remove the 'http' or 'https and 'www', then left over 'google.com' when given 'http://www.google.com'?

```
no_http_URL = regexp(domain_URL,'[a-z]+://','match','once')
```

The above code return me 'http' for the results, which is inverse to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
no_http_URL = regexp('http://google.com',     'https?://(?:www\.)?(.*)','tokens','once')
no_http_URL = regexp('http://www.google.com', 'https?://(?:www\.)?(.*)','tokens','once')
no_http_URL = regexp('https://google.com',    'https?://(?:www\.)?(.*)','tokens','once')
no_http_URL = regexp('https://www.google.com','https?://(?:www\.)?(.*)','tokens','once')
```

In expressions above the `no_http_URL` is `1x1 cell array`. If you need to access the string value you need to execute the following

```
no_http_URL = no_http_URL{1,1}
```

Comment: I can do it with this already 'no_http_URL = regexp(data,'(?<=www\.).*','match','once')' that return me 'google.com', but if my other data have 'https' or no 'www', it return me blank. I want it also return me the URL behind '.'

Comment: I have thousand of URLs, every URL has different character, I want to detect the '.' which behind 'www' and only take the left behind domain name.

Comment: @user3340270 Why don't you try to execute expressions above and see how do they work? As you can notice, all of them use same regex.

Comment: I can run with this, why I get the error after replacing 'tokens' with 'match', it show me '??? Error using ==> regexp
All cells for regexp must be strings.' Because I have to match with other criteria.

Comment: @user3340270 Can you explain full problem? I use `tokens` to extract `(.*)` part of regex. If you use `match` it will match the whole string.

Comment: ok, I have to use string in this case. if I want to solve this error '??? Error using ==> regexp
All cells for regexp must be strings.' Any ideas? or convert tokens to string?

Comment: because the next I will have to do this, 'split_URL = regexp(no_http_URL,'[:/.]*','split')
'

Comment: @user3340270 Then you first do `no_http_URL = regexp(...)`, then `no_http_URL = no_http_URL{1,1}`, then `split_URL = regexp(no_http_URL,...)`.

Comment: still return me the error, '
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> f7 at 14
    A7_data = split_URL{i};'

Comment: @user3340270 Does the following line work for you? `no_http_URL = regexp('https://www.google.com','https?://(?:www\.)?(.*)','tokens','once');no_http_URL = no_http_URL{1,1};split_URL = regexp(no_http_URL,'[:/.]*','split');`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51160/discussion-between-ulugbek-umirov-and-user3340270)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just remove the first 7 characters of the url, if it starts with http://?

Edit: Can't you find the first dot in the url and remove everything before it? I mean, put in a substring the characters after the dot.

Comment: I have thousand of URLs, every URL has different character, I want to detect the '.' which behind 'www' and only take the left behind domain name. I have to do it with coding and not manually.

Comment: so that is my question at here

Comment: Well, you don't need regular expressions to do that.

Comment: I can do it with this already 'no_http_URL = regexp(data,'(?<=http://www\.).*','match','once')' that return me 'google.com', but if my other data have 'https' or no 'www', it return me blank. I want it also return me the URL behind '.'

Comment: In that case, you need to study your data and identify the general cases. Eg: has http://domain, www.domain, http://www.domain etc